# Trying to use area functions ( with a graphing calculator) instead of calculating the integrals, but getting it wrong.

Tags: calculus, integration, soft-question

I'm working on problem 19.39 of Mendelson's 3000 Solved Problems Of Calculus.

> A particle is moving along a line with acceleration:
>   $$
> a = \sin(2t)+ t^2\ \mathrm{ft/s^2} . 
> $$
>
> At time $t=0$, the velocity is $3\ \mathrm{ft/s}$.
>
> What is the distance between the particle's location at $t=0$ and its location at $t=\frac{\pi}{2}$?

I tried to solve the problem without doing the calculations, using a graphing calculator and ***" area functions" ( playing the role of integrals)*** but I do not get the right result which out to be : 
$$
\frac{\pi^4+288\pi}{192}
$$
***What I do not understand is that, according to Mendelson's solution , the distance travelled at t=0 is not null***, but rather is equal to the constance C of the integral of the velocity  function. ( This I understand : distance is the integral of velocity).

***Why is the distance travelled at t=0 not null if, as I assume, t=0 is the beginning of the movement?***

Is this assumption wrong?

Also, ***why does the " area function "apprach" not work***?

Could you explain me what I am misssing?

Below, an image showing what I get with  the graphing calculator

[image]

Comment: Where have you used your initial condition that the initial velocity is $3$?

Comment: Yes... the initial condition *is* one of the givens in the problem.  And, by changing the initial condition, we should expect the final result to change.  As such, we should expect that somewhere within our calculations, the value given to us for the initial velocity should appear.

Comment: You're right I did not use it. I thought that the " area function" would correspond to the proper primitive , so that I would not have to use the initial condition to calculate the constant of integration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, $a(t) = \sin(2t)+t^2$

By integrating with respect to $t$ we get:

$v(t) = \int \sin(2t)+t^2~dt = -\frac{\cos(2t)}{2}+\frac{t^3}{3}+C$ for $C$ some constant

Remembering our initial condition that $v(0)=3$, we solve for $C$ as being $3.5$

Now... we can look at the definite integral of $v$ in order to determine the distance between the starting position and the ending position.  In particular, we are finding

$$\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}v(t)~dt = \int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\left( -\frac{\cos(2t)}{2}+\frac{t^3}{3}+3.5\right)~dt$$

$$=\left[-\frac{\sin(2t)}{4}+\frac{t^4}{12}+3.5t\right]^{t=\pi/2}_{t=0}$$

$$=\left(0+\frac{\pi^4}{12\cdot 2^4}+3.5\cdot \frac{\pi}{2}\right)-\left(0+0+0\right) = \frac{\pi^4+288\pi}{192}$$

Your error appears to have been using a definite integral when calculating $v(t)$ which would have given you the change in velocity over a time period rather than what the velocity *was* after a certain time.  By using an indefinite integral and calculating for the coefficient $C$ by using the provided initial conditions, you should have then been able to continue the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I missed the distinction between " change in velocity" and velocity value at a given time.